# Auto syncing provisioning profiles and certificates across machines

Tags: provisioning-profile

So up until this date I have been a lone developer working on a handful of iOS apps. Some have in app purchases, some have push notifications etc.

I have always allowed Xcode to auto manage the signing and never had any problems. However due to the success of the apps we have recruited a developer who will be working on the same apps on a separate machine. We also have setup a Mac mini to act as a build PC, (using a GitLab runner, it'll automatically build ad-hoc builds for testers.)

Now my understanding is this: both the Mac mini and other Mac will need a copy of the provisioning profile I am using and the development and distribution certificates from my keychain. I am assuming I'll have to turn auto signing off and manage it myself via the apple dev portal.

Is there a way I can auto sync the certificates and profiles across the machines?  So that if I need to change certificate etc I don't need to run round updating all machines.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to sync certificates and provisioning profiles across a team is Fastlane's [match](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/). It will require some work to set it up but it will be worth it in the long run.